# android- Calling Activity using customAction

Tags: android

I know there were some questions similar to this... but they didnt clear my issue.
I want to call an activity using setAction but i am getting run time exception..
"No Activity found to handle Intent"...
here is my manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.prem.intents.Main2Activity"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

here is my MainActivity code...

```
 b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s="com.example.prem.intents.Main2Activity";
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction(s);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try code in below in your manifest?

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.prem.intents.Main2Activity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In Documentation they says:

> To receive implicit intents, you must include the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare this category in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your activity.